# Is it possible to change bullet points to a custom picture?

Tags: css, image

```
<ul>
    <li>Walla Walla, WA</li>
    <li>Magic City, ID</li> 
    <li>Bountiful, UT</li> <li>Last Chance, CO</li>
    <li>Why, AZ</li> 
    <li>Truth or Consequences, NM.</li>
</ul>
```

I know how to make the bullet points, but I have no ideas in regard to how to change them.

Comment: Welcome TO SE Network Logan, did you try first? give us fiddle example so we can guide you nicely

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('sqpurple.gif');
}
```

This will change the bullet point to `sqpurple.gif`. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_list-style-image) are some more examples. Make sure your path to the image is correct though.